# pandas replace the asterisk sign from two columns in one go

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a called `host.txt` which further i'm parsing via pandas saving it again with current timestamp.

Below is the code which works fine except timestamp:

```
import pandas as pd
#--------------------
pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
#-----------------------------------------
MATCH_PATT = "AIX|CentOS|Fedora|RHEL|SunOS|SuSE|Ubuntu|(?<!\?)\?(?!\?)"
COLUMN_NAMES = ['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version']
df1 = pd.read_csv('/home/karn/plura/Test/Python_Panda/CyberArk/host.txt', delimiter = "\t", usecols=COLUMN_NAMES, encoding='cp1252',  dtype='unicode')
df2 = df1[df1['OS Version'].str.contains(MATCH_PATT,  na=False)][['Hostname', 'IP Address', 'Aux Site', 'OS Version']]
df2['Hostname'] = df2['Hostname'].str.replace("*", "")
df2['Aux Site'] = df2['Aux Site'].str.replace("*", "")
df2 = df2.iloc[:,0]
df2.to_csv('New_Surevy.txt.{}'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%y%m%d')))
```

Please advise how to get it, any clues will be much appreciated.

### Desired:

How we can replace the `*` sign from both `df2['Hostname']` and `df2['Aux Site']` in one go.

Comment: @harvpan, looks good let me try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the replace method with regex=True as such

```
df[['Hostname', 'Aux Site']] = df[['Hostname', 'Aux Site']].replace({'\*': ''}, regex=True)
```

Notice that this is the 'replace' method, not the 'str.replace' one.

Comment: Thanks @TPereira i'll check this.

Comment: Also don't forget the backslash, cause * is a special character in regex strings and you need to escape it if you want to replace it