# How to manipulate strings without copying columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove asterisks from strings in a pandas dataframe column efficiently.

I have tried the using replace function alone, but it doesn't change the values in my dataframe. If I use the following code, I get the desired effect:

```py
dfc['Trimmed Peptide'] = dfc['Trimmed Peptide'].str.replace('*', '', regex=False)
```

Unfortunately, I also get this warning: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead."

When I try

```py
dfc.loc['Trimmed Peptide'] = ...
```

I still get the error. How can I avoid copying the array?

Comment: The error is not from this code, it's from code that creates `dfc`. I suggest doing some reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/4909087

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759142/pandas-replace-the-asterisk-sign-from-two-columns-in-one-go#comment100076103_56759142